# How to get all running tasks in luigi, including dynamic ones

Tags: python, task, scheduled-tasks, luigi

I currently have a list of tasks that I run through the command

```
luigi.build(tasks, workers=N, local_scheduler=True, detailed_summary=True)
```

I would like to programmatically get the status of the local scheduler, hence I could not use global scheduler for my application. How can I get the list of running, pending, and completed tasks?

At first, I used to check for the creation of output files of some known tasks, but it is not efficient anymore since the complexity is increased and I also have dynamic tasks (`yield`ed by some other tasks at runtime).

I noticed that I could list dependencies through:

```
import luigi.tools.deps
luigi.tools.deps.find_deps(my_main_task, luigi.tools.deps.upstream().family)
```

but it is not helping more than looking at task's `output()`.

I have also noticed `Worker`s having a nice `_running_tasks` attribute, thus I would need to get the worker and list it, but I am also wondering about what happens if I have more than 1 worker with pending tasks along with running ones.